# Capturing video from web cam and process them with nacl - opencv

Tags: javascript, opencv, google-nativeclient

I'm planing to capture video using web cam and then process it with opencv and then finally show output on a web page with **opencv-naclport in google native-client environment**

The way i currently aware about is

1. Capture video from webcam using **MediaStreamTrack** interface in javascript and

then

2. Encode it to a **base64String** and send to the c++ module to process with opencv,
3. In cpp module decode it back to **Mat** image and process and finally send it back to the browser to display.

So i would like to know it it possible to capturing video with **VideoCapture** class in opencv instead of using **MediaStreamTrack** **and javascript**. Is there any limitations for accessing webcam from opencv due to sandbox constrains and whether above approach is correct/appropriate for processing and outputting image using webcam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of BASE64. Take a look at:
https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_dev/cpp/classpp_1_1_media_stream_video_track

Comment: Actually i got it done long ago. but wow this is much cleaner solution for my issue. Thank you i'll definitely look into that. and should consider re-writing it with this also. Extremely useful.